# Postgres substring finding space

Tags: regex, postgresql, substring

I'm trying to match a space in Postgres using substring.

I currently have: `substring((data)::text from '(?:"name":")([a-zA-Z0-9._-]*)'),`

The response of data would look like: `"name":"John Smith"...`
I want to match the full name, but sadly I seem to only be matching John. I tried adding `\s` without any luck. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Postgresql regex](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-matching.html) doesn't have any problem with `\s`. So I assume you have used the `\s` at the end of your regex just after the hyphen(`-`) and it made all the difference. For example

```
([a-zA-Z0-9._-\s]*)
              ^----- you see the hyphen here? it is the problem.
```

Inside a regex character-class `[]` `a-z` means any character from `a` to `z`.

So you have two solutions.

Escaping the hyphen with `\`

```
([a-zA-Z0-9._\-\s]*)
```

or, placing the \s at the elsewhere, lets say at the beginning.

```
([\sa-zA-Z0-9._-]*)
```

Now try!